# Message: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification in eclipse

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle, oracle10g

Below mentioned sql Trigger executed correctly in oracle sql plus

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger 
 BEFORE INSERT ON RESULTS
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 SELECT Pd_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.PT_ID FROM dual;
 END;
 /
```

But the same code, when implemented through java, threw the following error

CODE:

```
 ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger123 "+
                "BEFORE INSERT ON RESULTS"+
                "REFERENCING NEW AS NEW"+
                "FOR EACH ROW"+
                "BEGIN"+
                "SELECT Pd_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.PT_ID FROM dual;"+
                "END;"+
                "\n/");
```

Error Message in Eclipse:

```
SQL Exception:
State  : 42000
Message: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification

Error  : 4079
```

Kindly assist. What is causing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to insert a blank space or \n after each line. Example:

```
ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger123\n"+
                "BEFORE INSERT ON RESULTS\n"+
                "REFERENCING NEW AS NEW\n"+
                "FOR EACH ROW\n"+
                "BEGIN\n"+
                "SELECT Pd_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.PT_ID FROM dual;\n"+
                "END;\n"+
                "\n/");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to execute it like it is right now, it would look like this:

```
stmt.executeQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger123 BEFORE INSERT ON RESULTSREFERENCING NEW AS NEWFOR EACH ROWBEGINSELECT Pd_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.PT_ID FROM dual;END;\n/");
```

That's why you have to add spaces behind your lines.

```
ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery("CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger123 "+
            "BEFORE INSERT ON RESULTS "+
            "REFERENCING NEW AS NEW "+
            "FOR EACH ROW "+
            "BEGIN "+
            "SELECT Pd_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.PT_ID FROM dual; "+
            "END; "+
            "\n/");
```